# @Transactional doesn't perform commit

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, transactions

Please see my following code snippet.

```
@Transactional
public void saveMembersService(List<Member> list1, List<Member> list2)
{
    saveMembersDAO(list1); // does not perform commit. Why?
    saveMembersDAO(list2); // does not perform commit. Why?
} // does perform commit only here!

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Transactional
public void saveMembersDAO(List<Member> members)
    throws HibernateException
{
    Iterator<Member> it = members.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        Member wsBean = it.next();
        em.persist(wsBean); // overall commit will be made after method exit
    }
}
```

I use MySQL as DB. I watch MySql logs after above method execution. But I can see only **single** commit after *saveMembersService* method execution. I expect to see **two** commits for each transactional method invocation. Where am I wrong ?

**UPDATE 1:** Sorry, I have forgot to add @Transactional to my service method. It fixed now

**UPDATE 2:** I've checked with **Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW** attribute for DAO - result is the same (with and with out @Transactional at service method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When @Transactional is used, Spring creates a proxy around your class and methods called internally does not pass in the proxy.

You have to do this instead. You can clean it by creating your TransactionTemplate in your Spring context.

```
@Autowired
private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

public void saveMembersDAO(List<Member> members)
    throws HibernateException
{
    TransactionDefinition txDef = new DefaultTransactionDefinition(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
    TransactionTemplate txTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager, trDef)

    txTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {

        @Override
        protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
            Iterator<Member> it = members.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext())
            {
                Member wsBean = it.next();
                em.persist(wsBean);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

If you are using AspectJ and you want to have 2 commits. You must use a @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) on saveMembersDAO

Comment: Actually I've checked with Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW attribute for DAO - result is the same (with and with out @Transactional at service method)

Comment: Do you still have only a single commit?

Comment: Actually I've tried with _TransactionTemplate_ already - result is the same :( I still have only single commit

Comment: Was your TransactionDefinition PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW ?

Comment: Ooops, I had my _txTemplate_ at XML config and should add PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW directly. Thanks you was right!